# Setting the time in TDateTimePicker from linked DBEdit

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to convert time like "16:06:57.4400000" to a format that is compatible with TDateTimePicker

I have set some format settings

```pascal
  // Setting the Format Settings
  FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat:='yyyy-mm-dd';
  FormatSettings.DateSeparator  :='-';
  FormatSettings.LongTimeFormat :='hh:nn:ss';
  FormatSettings.TimeSeparator  :=':';
```

this line causes the error:

```pascal
  DateTimePicker2.Time := StrToTime(DBEdit4.Text);
```

[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sMVK.png)

how to convert properly?

Comment: Are you certain the time is stored as a string on the database side?

Comment: no, it's 'time' data type in the database, but the text from dbedit is string

Comment: Then use a datetimepicker that is db aware?

Comment: And if I remember correctly, `TDateTimePicker` has a `.Time` property?

Comment: I'm using delphi 10.3, what's the name of the component please because I couldn't find any datetimepicker that is db aware

Comment: yes it has the .Time property because I set the Kind to dtkTime

Comment: Then why are you using .Text? Or am I missing something here?

Comment: the point I use dbedits is because datetimepicker itself can't be linked to database, they act like a link between datetimepicker the database

Comment: Save yourself the pain and the agony, get a db aware picker, Google is your friend ("delphi db datetimepicker" ;) ) You are aware that you don't need the dbedit at all? get the value directly from the underlying dataset as a datetime value...

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, when you said "you don't need the dbedit at all" do you mean getting the data from ADOTable field and casting it to TTimeField?

Comment: yes, no need to cast, use the .AsDateTime method...

Comment: Thank you @whosrdaddy I appreciate your help